# Buddypress ORDER BY custom sort option on members directory

Tags: php, sorting, buddypress

I have implemented some custom sort options on the member directory of buddypress.  The one I am having an issue with is sort by Last Name (a xprofile field).  When I `print_r` the results of the query to the screen the user ID's are in the order I want them displayed in but when I visit the page the members are not in that order.  Reading up on bp_ajax_querystring I see you can pass ORDER and ORDERBY but anything I have tried doesnt work.  The members should display in alphabetical order by last name.

Here is the piece of code with the query.

```
if( $ch_querystring['type'] == 'alphabetical-last' ){

        global $wpdb;

        $field_id = 518; //Last name field ID

        $query = "SELECT user_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = " . $field_id . " ORDER BY " . $wpdb->prefix . "bp_xprofile_data.value ASC";

        $custom_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

        // convert the array to a csv string
        $user_str = implode(",", $custom_ids);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($user_str); //Prints the ID's I would like the members to be displayed in
        echo '</pre>';

        $ch_querystring['include'] = $user_str; 
        //$ch_querystring['type'] = 'alphabetical'; 
        $ch_querystring['per_page'] = 500;
        $ch_querystring['exclude'] = '1,1101,1030';
        //$ch_querystring['orderby'] = "ORDER BY FIELD(value," . $ch_querystring['include'] . ")";  //Doesnt Work
        //$ch_querystring['order'] = 'DESC'; //ASC and DESC doesnt work
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($ch_querystring);
        echo '</pre>';

        return $ch_querystring;

    }
```

For debugging here is what `$ch_querystring` returns:

```
Array
(
    [type] => alphabetical-last
    [action] => alphabetical-last
    [scope] => all
    [page] => 1
    [user_id] => 0
    [search_terms] => 
    [exclude] => 1,1101,1030
    [per_page] => 500
    [include] => 1511,1499,1477,1483,1,1512,1510,1482,1503,1514,1498,1502,1506,1484,1479,1492,1497,1488,1495,1508,1475,1481,1501,1515,1478,1491,1490,1505,1487,1509,1480,1507,1485,1493,1513,1500,1516,1496,1476,1489,1504,1494,1486,1474
    [orderby] => ORDER BY FIELD(value,1511,1499,1477,1483,1,1512,1510,1482,1503,1514,1498,1502,1506,1484,1479,1492,1497,1488,1495,1508,1475,1481,1501,1515,1478,1491,1490,1505,1487,1509,1480,1507,1485,1493,1513,1500,1516,1496,1476,1489,1504,1494,1486,1474)
)
```

Here is a link to a [paste with the full code](http://pastebin.com/53sN5gLu) in case it helps

Answer (score 0):

I needed a helper function to sort the query using something similar to this: 
https://buddypress.org/support/topic/sort-user-list-by-last-name/

```
//Helper for sorting by last name
function alphabetize_by_last_name( $bp_user_query ) {
    if ( 'alphabetical-last' == $bp_user_query->query_vars['type'] )
        $bp_user_query->uid_clauses['orderby'] = "ORDER BY substring_index(u.display_name, ' ', -1)";
}
add_action ( 'bp_pre_user_query', 'alphabetize_by_last_name' );
```